# Quadratic Equation using surds property

Tags: quadratics

$$\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^x+\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^x=2^x$$

Using property of surd can we simplify the above expression like:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^x +\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^x=2^x$$

Am I right here please guide....

Comment: Yes we can. But is it easier to solve?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. Since you know that $$\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\pm1}{\sqrt{2}},$$ you can always make such a substitution. All you're doing is rewriting the same thing in a different-looking form, and there's no problem with doing that.

---

I'd take a different route, though. Since $\sqrt{\alpha}=\alpha^{1/2}$ for any positive $\alpha$, we can rewrite the equation using exponential properties as $$\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{x/2}+\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{x/2}=4^{x/2},$$ then make the substitution $y=x/2$ to get $$\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^y+\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^y=4^y.$$ It should be clear just by looking that $y=1$ ($x=2$) provides a solution to this equation. In fact, it is the *only* solution, which can be proved in various ways.

Comment: How to do substitution here because of R.H.S = $2^x$

Comment: You can make a substitution with an equivalent expression anywhere in any equation. There is no need to make substitutions for *every* expression in an equation. Your substitutions may not do you a lot of good, but there's certainly nothing preventing you from making them.

Comment: Let me suggest an alternative approach. I will edit my answer now.

Comment: And of course: $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}$$